# how can you perform an onclick function only on a specific item from an array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm mapping through an array but I only want to select a specific item so I can make an onlick in it and for it to perform an specific action but I don't know how to only select that item instead of all the items in the array.

I want to only select the "Sign out" from the profile's variable. Any help I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { BellIcon, MenuIcon, XIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'

const navigation = ['Dashboard', 'Clients', 'Meals', 'Calendar']
const profile = ['Your Profile', 'Settings', 'Sign out']

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Disclosure as="nav" className="bg-gray-800">
        {({ open }) => (
          <>
            <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                    <img
                      className="h-8 w-8"
                      src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-500.svg"
                      alt="Workflow"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="hidden md:block">
                    <div className="ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-4">
                      {navigation.map((item, itemIdx) =>
                        itemIdx === 0 ? (
                          <Fragment key={item}>
                            {/* Current: "bg-gray-900 text-white", Default: "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white" */}
                            <a href="/dashboard" className="bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">
                              {item}
                            </a>
                          </Fragment>
                        ) : (
                          <a
                            key={item}
                            href={`/${item}`}
                            className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                          >
                            {item}
                          </a>
                        )
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="hidden md:block">
                  <div className="ml-4 flex items-center md:ml-6">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="bg-gray-800 p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                    >
                      <span className="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                      <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>

                    {/* Profile dropdown */}
                    <Menu as="div" className="ml-3 relative">
                      <div>
                        <Menu.Button className="max-w-xs bg-gray-800 rounded-full flex items-center text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
                          <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                          <img
                            className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </Menu.Button>
                      </div>
                      <Transition
                        as={Fragment}
                        enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                      >
                        <Menu.Items className="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                          {profile.map((item) => (
                            <Menu.Item key={item}>
                              {({ active }) => (
                                <a
                                  href="#"
                                  className={classNames(
                                    active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '',
                                    'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700'
                                  )}
                                >
                                  {item}
                                </a>
                              )}
                            </Menu.Item>
                          ))}
                        </Menu.Items>
                      </Transition>
                    </Menu>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">




                  {/* Mobile menu button */}
                  <Disclosure.Button className="bg-gray-800 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
                    <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                    {open ? (
                      <XIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    ) : (
                      <MenuIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    )}
                  </Disclosure.Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <Disclosure.Panel className="md:hidden">
              <div className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
                {navigation.map((item, itemIdx) =>
                  itemIdx === 0 ? (
                    <Fragment key={item}>
                      {/* Current: "bg-gray-900 text-white", Default: "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white" */}
                      <a href="#" className="bg-gray-900 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">
                        {item}
                      </a>
                    </Fragment>
                  ) : (
                    <a
                      key={item}
                      href="#"
                      className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                    >
                      {item}
                    </a>
                  )
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="pt-4 pb-3 border-t border-gray-700">
                <div className="flex items-center px-5">
                  <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                    <img
                      className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
                      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="ml-3">
                    <div className="text-base font-medium leading-none text-white">Tom Cook</div>
                    <div className="text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-400">tom@example.com</div>
                  </div>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="ml-auto bg-gray-800 flex-shrink-0 p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                  >
                    <span className="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                    <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-3 px-2 space-y-1">
                  {profile.map((item) => (
                    <a
                      key={item}
                      href="#"
                      className="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700"
                    >
                      {item}
                    </a>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </Disclosure.Panel>
          </>
        )}
      </Disclosure>

    
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I assume that you want to apply onclick to the `Menu.Items`**

So just check for the `item==='Sign out'` then put your handler there.

```
<Menu.Items className="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
  {profile.map((item) => (
    <Menu.Item key={item} onClick={item === "Sign out" && handleSomething()}>
      {({ active }) => (
        <a
          href="#"
          className={classNames(
            active ? "bg-gray-100" : "",
            "block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700"
          )}
        >
          {item}
        </a>
      )}
    </Menu.Item>
  ))}
</Menu.Items>;
```